# How to control what Tensorflow CPU feature tos be compiled into the binary?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm having runtime errors when running Tensorflow programs. I tracked down the problem and the source seems to be that the shared object I have compiled includes CPU features that are not supported by my processor. That causes some pointers pointing to invalid addresses. Right now there are 37 CPU feature defined in tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_info.h. My question is how to not include some of those when compiling Tensorflow's source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `./configure` option for optimization flags to the compiler (`CC_OPT_FLAGS`). By default this is `-march=native`, which will try to include instructions supported by the current architecture. You can turn off some of these manually with e.g. `-mno-avx` to turn off AVX.